# Can we use condition in the endpoint value of an API call?

Tags: javascript, api

Suppose, An API call is made with value like 'abc'.

```
const response = fetch('anything.com/any/abc');
```

But, Can we make an API call to fetch all the values from the database starting with 'a'?
Can we use condition in the endpoint value of an API call?
If yes how can we do that?

Comment: Only if the API supports such syntax

Comment: then what will be the syntax of the APIs which supports it?

Comment: Depends on the API. You could design it however you wanted.

Comment: If we said the answer was yes, what else would you like to know? This question lends itself to a "yes/no" answer.

Comment: How can we do that?

Comment: The question is, did you make the API or are you using an API that was made elsewhere? if you made it, then you can program it how you like, but if you are connecting to someone else's API, then you will need to consult their docs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the API.

Probably what you're looking for is an API compliant to the [OData specification](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.01-os-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc31360957)

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so clear. Are you dealing with a your own API or a 3rd party API ?

Anyway it is a problem API side, you can't use conditional filtering if the features is not provided.